# Credentials needed for BT line on Netgear router

Tags: router, internet

I have recently bought a new Netgear router to replace my current BTHomeHub as it doesn't support wireless. I did buy a WAP but figured it would be easier to use a router with wireless built in. (It's a modem/router combo).

I have got as far as setting up the router on the web interface, but then it asks for a username and password to connect to the net, I can only assume this is for the phone line?

I have tried some passwords I could find written down but they don't work, the internet light comes on and then when the creds fail it goes off.

I have been on the homehubs web interface and been through all the settings it has to find the credentials it is using which obviously work, but no joy.

Is there anything obvious I am missing, or is there a way I can retrieve my settings from my existing router?

Any pointers will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the username is displayed in the homehub, but the password is not.

you should have been emailed your username by BT when the service was started, if you have lost this email, you can could call BT and confirm the password with them.

you will need you account number, address and postcode, and possibly other information to authenticate to BT.